# NativeScript http.getJSON and async await

Tags: javascript, api, request, nativescript

I have problems with processing return after promise in my NativeScript app. Return get executed before **http.getJSON** gets data. It's just skip the return unchanged (status) variable. I have tried to use **await** but that did not work or I did not use it correctly. Here is my code

```
const check = {  
CheckLenght: function(id) { 
    var status = false; 
    var response = checkPoints(id); 

    if(response > 10){
        status true;
    } else {
        status false;
    } 

    console.log("This is response: " + status); // this shows up before getJSON is returned as "This is response: false"

    return status;  // always returns false
 }  
} 


function checkPoints(id){
    let points; 
    http.getJSON('MY_API_URL' + id)
   .then(function (response) {  
        points = response[0].point; 
   }, function(error) {
       console.log("Server err."); 
   }) 

 console.log("This output shows up before - This is response: false ");
 return points;  
}
```

Is there a way to get this working? I tried with Observable but that did not work ether.

**UPDATE:**

Here is code from where I make a call to `CheckLenght: function(id)` using `var resp = ProvjeraBarcode.CheckLenght(result.text);` and it returns [object Promise]

```
function skeniraj(){ 
barcodescanner.scan({
    formats: "QR_CODE, EAN_13",    
    cancelLabel: "Odustani. Probajte Volume tipke",  
    closeCallback: function () { console.log("Scanner closed"); },  
    openSettingsIfPermissionWasPreviouslyDenied: true  
  }).then(
      function(result) {
        console.log("Scan format: " + result.format);
        console.log("Scan text:   " + result.text);  

//#########################            

      var resp = ProvjeraBarcode.CheckLenght(result.text);

//########################## 

       console.log("Show response: "+JSON.stringify(resp)); 
       // output is: "[object Promise]"


        if(resp === "true"){ 
            // if true... 
                setTimeout(func, 50);
                function func() {
                    dialogs.confirm({
                        title: "Kartica je valjana",
                        message: "Pohranite karticu u memoriju?",
                        okButtonText: "Pohrani",
                        cancelButtonText: "Odustani", 
                    }).then(function (response) { 
                        console.log("Dialog result: " + response);
                        if(response){  
                        // save details to storage...

                        } 
                    });
                } 

            } else {
                // .... do something else...
            } 
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log("Nista nije skenirano Err. " + error);
        // pokreni rucni unos
        setTimeout(rucniUnos, 50); 
      }
  ); 
 }
```

I'm having hard times with this. Thanks for all help and support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your code this way:

```
function checkPoints(id){

  let points;
  // make a new variable, nothing is assigned so give it undefined

  http.getJSON('MY_API_URL' + id).then(...)
  // Promise? handle later, go to next line.

  return points;
  // return undefined
}
```

Points will always be `undefined`. <s>You assign `point` inside of `http.getJSON`'s `then`, so actually even if that function was synchronous, `point` of the outer scope would still be `undefined`.</s> **Edit** You wouldn’t had used `then` if the function were synchronous & `point` would had been modified, my bad!

You can change your code so that `checkPoints()` returns a Promise, which ensure you the data has been returned.

```
function checkPoints(id){
  return http.getJSON('MY_API_URL' + id).then(
    function (response) {  
      return response[0].point;  <-- return the response[0].point
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("Server err."); 
    })
}
```

or with arrow function

```
const checkPoints = (id) => http.getJSON(`MY_API_URL${id}`)
  .then(response => response[0].point)
  .catch(error => console.log("Server err."))
```

And in your function you can use async / await:

```
...
//             V checkLengtht has to be an async function, otherwise it can't use await
CheckLenght: async function(id) { 
  var status = false;
  var response = await checkPoints(id);
      if(response > 10){
        status true;
    } else {
        status false;
    }
  return status;
}
```

You can rewrite your code like this:

```
CheckLenght: async function(id) { 
  const points = await checkPoints(id);
  return (points > 10) // return true if points > 10, else return false. Note that this function's return will be wrapped in Promise.
}
```

Note that CheckLength's is now an async function, meaning it returns Promise; when you use it, you have to use `await` or `.then()`.

You can also do away with async/await entirely:

```
...
CheckLenght: id => checkPoints(id).then(points => points > 10);
```

---

### How to use async/await

Appending `async` in front of function declaration makes it returns a Promise.

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b
add(1, 2) // 3

const add = async (a, b) => a + b
add(1, 2) // Promise(...)
add(1, 2).then(res => console.log(res)) // 3
```

`await` can be used inside an `async` function to retrive response of a Promise.

```
const main = async () => {
  const res = await add(1, 2)
  console.log(res)
}

main() // 3
```

Comment: Thanks for long and detailed explanation. I managed to make similar thing (longer and not clean and yours) but CheckLenght: async function(id) returns [object Promise] to the function which requests data: 
var resp = CheckAPI.CheckLenght(result.text).toString();
// check data.. do something if response is true.
if(resp === "true"){ ....} else {....}

Do I have to call it with await as well?

Comment: That's right, `async` wraps function into returning Promise, so you'd have to call it with await as well; or if that's not possible (await has to be called within _another_ async function); use `.then()` callback (a.k.a `CheckAPI.CheckLength(...).then(result => ...)`)

Comment: thanks it worked. :D I understand it better now. Learning on hard way. Thanks for support!